# GetJson parse function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

here is my code for parsing JSON data of geolocation api of google

```
 var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + input.value + "&sensor=false";

   var check = $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            console.log("inside getjson");
            $.each(data.results.address_components, function(){

             if(this.types[0]=="route"){
         $("#results").append('<p> route : '+this.long_name +'</p>');
    } 

    if(this.types[0]=="locality"){
        $("#results").append('<p> locality : '+this.long_name +'</p>');
    } 


    if(this.types[0]=="administrative_area_level_2"){
        $("#results").append('<p> administrative area 2 : '+this.long_name +'</p>');
    } 

    if(this.types[0]=="administrative_area_level_1"){
        $("#results").append('<p> administrative area 1 : '+this.long_name +'</p>');
    } 


    if(this.types[0]=="country"){
        $("#results").append('<p> country : '+this.long_name +'</p>');
    } 


           // latitude1 =  data.results[0].geometry.location.lat; 
           // longitude1 = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

           //alert(data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
    });


    });
```

but unfortunately it doesn't parse the data properly...firebug throws the error as e not defined. can you please look into it

Comment: `console.log(data);` Does that print a string or an object?

Comment: @RichardA yes, its an object ....you can access json from the url mentioned in the code..replace input.value by any address

Comment: What is the stack trace? The name of an internal variable is not very helpful

Comment: please check 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549356/json-parse-with-jquery-loop

Comment: If you can provide an example of `input.value` it would make it easier to test your output.