# json parse with jQuery loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

hi my code is attached below, though its a part of bigger code

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#results{margin-top:100px; width:600px; border:1px solid #000000; background-color:#CCCCCC; min-height:200px;}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="results"></div>

<script>

var input="Taj Mahal India";

var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + input + "&sensor=false";

   var check = $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            console.log("inside getjson");
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data.results.address_components, function(i,inside){

             if(inside.types[0]=="route"){
         $("#results").append('<p> route : '+this.long_name +'</p>');
    }   
    if(inside.types[0]=="locality"){
        $("#results").append('<p> locality : '+this.long_name +'</p>');
    } 

    if(inside.types[0]=="administrative_area_level_2"){
        $("#results").append('<p> administrative area 2 : '+this.long_name +'</p>');
    }   
    if(inside.types[0]=="administrative_area_level_1"){
        $("#results").append('<p> administrative area 1 : '+this.long_name +'</p>');
    } 

    if(inside.types[0]=="country"){
        $("#results").append('<p> country : '+this.long_name +'</p>');
    } 

    }); 
    });

    </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

The problem is that it doesn't work. I have a strong doubt that i have done something wrong in `$.each(data.results.address_components, function(i,inside)` line.

JSON for Taj Mahal India is here http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Taj%20Mahal%20India&sensor=false

Comment: Can you tell us what you are expecting it to do, and what it _is_ doing that you don't expect?

Comment: @Xymostech when i run it in browser it doesn't print anything
it throws an error in firebug which is beyond my understanding, it says e in not defined.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549089/getjson-parse-function/18549234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
$.each(data.results[0].address_components, function(i,inside)
```

instead of

```
$.each(data.results.address_components, function(i,inside)
```

because you are taking data from the first `results` set. Here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/F3TMF/)

**Note:** I don't know if there can be multiple `results`. If it can, then you must first iterate over the `results` and then inside it on `address_components`.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful of the scope of the '`this`' keyword, and it needs `results[0]` as @Harry pointed out. The following is untested:

```
var check = $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    console.log("inside getjson");
    console.log(data);
    $.each(data.results[0].address_components, function(i,inside){
        if(inside.types[0]=="route"){
            $("#results").append('<p> route : '+inside.long_name +'</p>');
        }
        if(inside.types[0]=="locality"){
            $("#results").append('<p> locality : '+inside.long_name +'</p>');
        } 
        if(inside.types[0]=="administrative_area_level_2"){
            $("#results").append('<p> administrative area 2 : '+inside.long_name +'</p>');
        }   
        if(inside.types[0]=="administrative_area_level_1"){
            $("#results").append('<p> administrative area 1 : '+inside.long_name +'</p>');
        } 
        if(inside.types[0]=="country"){
            $("#results").append('<p> country : '+inside.long_name +'</p>');
        } 
    }); 
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/F3TMF/) by @Harry

Comment: @Moob: If you don't mind, you can add this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/F3TMF/) to your answer :)

Comment: @Harry: So added, but since you found the problem first perhaps you should post it as your own answer.